# How to get count of documents with unique words present in an opensearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Suppose I have an index `test_index` and it contains 2 documents:

1. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
2. There was a brown fox

I want to write a query which can display the count of documents for all unique words. So the output is going to be something like this:

1. The - 1
2. quick - 1
3. brown - 2
4. fox - 2
5. jumps - 1
6. 

and so on.

What query should be written to achieve this in opensearch

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is one possible query to achieve that result but to get the frequency of some words that you specifically want, you could use [term vectors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html#docs-termvectors-api-term-stats) and get the most frequent words as well.

> Setting term_statistics to true (default is false) will return
>
> - total term frequency (how often a term occurs in all documents)
> - document frequency (the number of documents containing the current term)

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this in a consolidated way is to [enable `fielddata`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#fielddata-mapping-param) on your text field.

Let's say you have a field named `content` of type `text` that contains the data you want to analyze, then you need to modify your mapping like this:

```
PUT test/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "content": {
      "type": "text",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can run a `terms` aggregation on that field like this:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "usage": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "content",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And you'd get what you expect:

```
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "usage" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 1,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "brown",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "fox",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "a",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "dog",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "jumps",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "lazy",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "over",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "quick",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "the",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "there",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE**, however, that this is **strongly discouraged** as field data is loaded in memory and depending on the volume of data on which you run this, this can consume significant memory.